How do i add filtration by metadata to EnsembleRetriever.invoke() made with FIASS.as_retrivier() and BM25Retriever from LungChain?
My data is messages wit label ('supply', 'demand') as metadata:
Document(metadata={'label': 'supply'}, page_content="I want to sell smth")

and i have a query to search pair for:
query = 'I want to buy smth'

Here is my code:
vectorstore = FAISS.from_embeddings(text_embeddings, metadatas=metadatas, embedding=model)
dense_retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()
bm25_retriever = BM25Retriever.from_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas)
ensemble_retriever = EnsembleRetriever(retrievers=[dense_retriever, bm25_retriever], weights=[0.8, 0.2])

ensemble_retriever.invoke("I want to buy smth")

if the query label is "demand" ensemble_retriever should seek only for pair that class is "supply".
Is there a way to add filtration to both of retriviers?
What i tried:
ensemble_retriever.invoke("I want to buy smth", filter={'label':'supply')

but as kwargs it doesn`t work nor as anything else work as kwarg argument like k...
And i tried:
dense_retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'filter':{'label':'demand'}, 'k': 3})

but its rather not than works and i dont want to initilize retrivier every search :|
!!!!!
UPD It is not possible in current version
